# $A=\frac{\mathbb{C}[X,Y]}{(X^2+Y^2-1)}$ is a PID.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

I was given an exercise to show $A=\frac{\mathbb{C}[X,Y]}{(X^2+Y^2-1)}$ is a PID. But I wonder if it is true. Note that PID $\implies$ UFD. But we have
$$X\cdot X = 1-Y^2 =(1-Y)(1+Y)$$
in $A$ which contradicts UFD.

> Is there something wrong in the above factorization? Any suggestions / hints.

Edit: I can prove mechanically it is PID. My main concern was the above factorization. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5591/are-quotients-of-polynomial-rings-almost-ufds @ZachTeitler Here the base field is $\mathbb{C}$, which allows you to break $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$. You will not have this decomposition when the base field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This is a good question. I've seen many solutions of some similar questions based on such a quick "argument", but this isn't enough. You have to show that $x,1-y,1+y$ are irreducible and non-associates. But  $x$ (for instance) is not irreducible in $A$ since we have $x=\frac{(x+iy+i)(x+iy-i)}{2(x+iy)}$.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. And $1+y = \frac{1}{2}(x-iy)(x+iy+i)^2$. So it's not that $x$ is associated to $1\pm y$, it's that $x$ and $1\pm y$ are reducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is essentially here, but I will detail it to get this off the unanswered questions list.

As Georges Elencwajg observed in [his answer to the corresponding MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5596/9947), the linear substitution $u:=x+iy$ and $v:=x-iy$ is invertible and therefore $\Bbb C[u,v]=\Bbb C[x,y]$. Furthermore,
$$
uv = (x+iy)(x-iy)= x^2+y^2
$$
so the ring in question is $\Bbb C[u,v]/(uv-1)$, which is the same as $\Bbb C[u,u^ {-1}]$. Now, let us invert this linear transformation to understand the factorization of $x^2$.

We have $x=u-iy$ and $y=i(v-x)$. Hence, $x=u+v-x$, meaning 
$$
x=\frac{u+v}2=\frac{u+u^{-1}}2=\frac{u^2+1}{2u}=\frac{u-i}{2u}\cdot\frac{u+i}{2u}
$$ 
is not even irreducible and similarly,
$$
y = i\cdot \left(v-\frac{u+v}2\right)=i\cdot\frac{v-u}2=\frac{u-u^{-1}}{2i}
= \frac{u^2-1}{2iu}=\frac{u-1}{2iu}\cdot\frac{u+1}{2iu}
$$
isn't either. Now,
$$
1-y=\frac{2iu-u^2+1}{2iu}=\frac{(u-i)^2}{2ui}
$$
and
$$
1+y = \frac{2iu+u^2-1}{2iu} = \frac{(u+i)^2}{2iu}
$$
explains that you have simply redistributed your irreducible factors and it all really makes sense.